How can I mute/unmute a microphone using WebRTC and PeerJs?
I'm trying to get the user to mute their microphone so that the other user on the call can't hear them, but I've failed in every attempt.
I just wish the caller or callee could mute themselves so that one can't hear the other.
By the way, the user can establish a connection, I can hear and be heard, I can end the call, etc., the only problem is the mute/unmute, besides, am I using good practices in this code?
This is my code:
if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(function(stream) {
        let currentCall = null;
        let remoteAudioElement = null;
        var localStream = stream;

        // Atender a chamada e fornecer a MediaStream
        peer.on('call', function(call) {
            currentCall = call;
            
            incommingCallToast.show();
            document.getElementById('callerUsername').innerText = call.metadata.callerUsername;

            document.getElementById('acceptCallButton').onclick = function() {
                incommingCallToast.hide();
                call.answer(localStream);  // Use apenas localStream aqui
                call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
                    remoteAudioElement = new Audio();
                    remoteAudioElement.srcObject = remoteStream;
                    remoteAudioElement.play();
                    document.getElementById('endCallButton').style.display = 'flex';
                });

                call.on('close', function() {
                    incommingCallToast.hide();
                    showErrorToast('Chamada encerrada.');
                    document.getElementById('endCallButton').style.display = 'none';
                });
            };

            document.getElementById('rejectCallButton').onclick = function() {
                incommingCallToast.hide();
                call.close();
            };
        });

        // Realizar a chamada ao clicar no botão
        document.getElementById('audioCallButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: `/friends/${currentFriendId}`,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.friend) {
                        const friend = data.friend;

                        if(!friend.online)
                            return showErrorToast("O seu amigo está offline, portanto não pode receber chamadas.");

                        document.getElementById('calleeUsername').innerText = friend.username;
                        callingToast.show();

                        console.log('Calling peer ID: ' + friend.peerid);

                        var call = peer.call(friend.peerid, localStream, {
                            metadata: { callerUsername: currentUsername }
                        });

                        currentCall = call;

                        call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
                            remoteAudioElement = new Audio();
                            remoteAudioElement.srcObject = remoteStream;
                            remoteAudioElement.play();
                            document.getElementById('endCallButton').style.display = 'flex';
                            callingToast.hide();
                        });

                        document.getElementById('rejectCallButton').onclick = function() {
                            callingToast.hide();
                            call.close();
                        };

                        call.on('close', function() {
                            callingToast.hide();
                            showErrorToast('Chamada encerrada.');
                            document.getElementById('endCallButton').style.display = 'none';
                        });

                    } else {
                        showErrorToast('Dados do amigo não encontrado.');
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    const errorMessage = jqXHR.responseJSON ? jqXHR.responseJSON.error : 'Dados do amigo não encontrados.';
                    showErrorToast(errorMessage);
                }
            });
        });

        document.getElementById('endCallButton').onclick = function() {
            callingToast.hide();

            if (currentCall) {
                currentCall.close();
                currentCall = null;
                document.getElementById('endCallButton').style.display = 'none';
                showErrorToast('Chamada encerrada.');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('endCallButton').style.display = 'none';
                showErrorToast('Nenhuma chamada ativa para encerrar.');
            }
        };

        // Controlar volume e mute
        var muteButton = document.getElementById('muteButton');
        var isMuted = false;

        muteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const icon = muteButton.querySelector('i');
            if (remoteAudioElement) {
                isMuted = !isMuted;
                remoteAudioElement.muted = isMuted;

                if (isMuted) {
                    icon.classList.remove('fa-microphone');
                    icon.classList.add('fa-microphone-slash');
                    icon.style.color = '#FF6347'; // Define a cor para '#FF6347' quando o microfone está mutado
                } else {
                    icon.classList.remove('fa-microphone-slash');
                    icon.classList.add('fa-microphone');
                    icon.style.color = 'white'; // Define a cor para 'white' quando o microfone está desmutado
                }
            }
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        showErrorToast('Failed to get local stream', err);
    });
} else {
    showErrorToast('Seu navegador não suporta a API getUserMedia.');
}

